# Deleted branch on remote repository, but GIT says i'm in sync?

Tags: git, github

I pushed some code to my origin remote repository, which is forked from the original on GitHub.

I accidentally did a `git push`, instead of specifying that I wanted to push to the master branch on the remote. So, I have a branch called `tabFix`, and it pushed to `origin/tabFix` branch.

I tried to fix this by deleting the `origin/tabFix` branch.

Now Git is telling me that everything is up to date. It is also telling me to run:

> use `git branch --unset-upstream` to fixup

which I am suspicious of.

Running the command: `push origin master` tells me everything is up-to-date.

What I want is to push the changes in my `tabFix` branch locally to the `origin/master` branch. How can I reset the system so it sees my changes as actual changes, and allows me to do this?

Comment: Probably your local is not tracking your intended remote branch. You can check it by `git branch -vv`. If is not tracking your origin/master, You can set it to track your remote by command `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master`

Comment: How did you delete `origin/tabFix`?

Comment: i deleted origin/tabFix on gitHub itself. Probably a dumb idea, but i wanted to experiment and i figured i could just blow away the repository and reimplement the changes if it all went south...lol

Comment: yeah, the command: git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master totally fixed it. i was then able to use "git push origin HEAD:master" to push to the origin master, and it LOOKS like everything is peachy again. thanks!

Comment: @PeterAndrus Done.

Comment: @PeterAndrus: you can *run* `git push origin HEAD:master` at any time, but it only *makes sense* if you want to set the other Git's `master` to match your current commit (which in this case you did want). The upstream setting of a branch is meant to make things convenient—it does not control things, it just makes them easier (or intentionally harder to avoid various mistakes). Git is a collection of tools that you can use in many different ways, not a specific set of procedures you must always follow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your local is not tracking your intended remote branch.

You can check it by `git branch -vv`. If it is not tracking your `origin/master`, You can set it to track your remote by command `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master`